# How to set the title of the scene that's a child of a tab using react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I've this route:

```
    export default props => (
        <Router>
            <Stack key="root" hideNavBar>
                <Tabs key='tabs'
                      tabs={true}
                      initial
                      tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor: THEME_NAVBAR_AND_TABBAR}}
                      showLabel={false}>
                    <Scene key='events' component={Events} title='Events' icon={TabIcon}/>

                </Tabs>
            </Stack>
        </Router>
    )
```

On my Events components, I've this:

```
 import React from 'react'
 import {View, Text, ScrollView, TouchableWithoutFeedback, 
 TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
 import {connect} from "react-redux"

 import style from './style'
 import {Actions} from "react-native-router-flux";

class Events extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        loaded: false
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    Actions.refresh({ title: 'xxxx' })
}
render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={style.scene}>

        </ScrollView>
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => (
{
    events: state.ContentReducer.events
}
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
{

})(Events)
```

But it's being ignored. Probably because the scene is a child of the Tabs. How to make this change ? (it must me inside the component - cannot be on the router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many research and trial/errors, I found a solution:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
            title: 'xxxx'
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the tabs by default load all scenes nested, you can pass the props "lazy" to prevent that. But if you open the scene one time you will need to use componentWillReceiveProps to get the new props, because the scene will stand open even if you change the tab.

On Events component scene you can use the title as a state then use componentWillMount function to get the title and componentWillReceiveProps function to get the new title when it changes.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.setState({title: this.props.title});
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  //new title
  this.setState({title: newProps.title});
}
```

Comment: Thanx, Alessandro ! this make sense. But can you tell me exactly what I supposed to do on the router to archive it ? Plz edit your answer. Gracias !

Comment: @MarcoJr I can you post the Events component? i can help you more.

Comment: of course I can ! I just edited the code for you. But it's a very naked scene anyway. Let me know if you need more !

Comment: @MarcoJr Ok, first sorry i miss understand what are you trying to do, but to change the TABBAR title you can use Actions.Events({title: "Novo Titulo"}) or you can pass the key on Actions.refresh({key: "Events", title: "Novo Titulo" }). do not confuse with the NAVBAR title with is showed on the top of the screen.

Comment: Looks like you are a pt-BR just like me :) Well....no, no lucky...I read before about this solution and I attempted:  Actions.refresh({
            key: 'events',
            title: 'xxxx' })
        Actions.events({title : 'yyyy'})
None of the lines above solve it...  It's frustrating, but I appreciate your efforts indeed.

Comment: @MarcoJr Did you check the tabbar for any changes ? i made a app to test and it worked fine.

Comment: But I want to change the title of the navbar, Alessandro. I mean: the title that goes on the top